# Incorporating constraints in relaxed manner in CP-SAT

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have a fairly easy problem setting. I want to Add a `const` value to a decision variables `x` and `y` after models finds `x`  and `y` with already defined constraints. But I want to add that `const` value only if the new `x` and `y` values are in their domain range and follows all other constraints.

I attempted the problem as follows:

```
"""Model finding x and y values based on previously defined constraints"""

# defines NewBoolVar(b1, b2)
# This is the trick I tried to used
# defined a temporary bool var - NewBoolVar(temp_bool) and always wants it to be true

model.Add(1>=0).OnlyEnforceIf(temp_bool)     #always keeps temp_bool true

model.Add(x == x + const). OnlyEnforceIf(b1)
model.Add(y == y + const). OnlyEnforceIf(b2)

model.AddBoolOr([b1, temp_bool])
model.AddBoolOr([b2, temp_bool])
```

with the above formulation I assume the model should give what I expect it to give. But I am not getting what I want. Even `x` and `y` being in domain range and follows other constraints they are not added with the `const` value. I agree that I have this `temp_bool` variable which is doing it job and not giving me the expected results.

So I want to know is there any trick which I can use to get what I expect? Any other way one can suggest?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is correct in what your wrote:

- `==` is not an assignment but an equality test. Thus it will always fail.
- `model.Add(1 >= 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b)`: what is that??? `model.AddBoolOr(b)` or `slightly worse model.Add(b == 1)`.
- Furthermore, your equation is logically equivalent to `b implies true` which is actually does not impact `b`. Both `b=true` and `b=false` are valid solutions.
- `model.AddBoolOr(b1, temp_bool)`: temp_bool is always true. The the bool_or is always satisfied and does not constrain `b1`.

Comment: I always thought that OnlyEnforceif() will make the boolean variable true if the constraint it is tied up with is satisfied. Hence I used that. I will make the necessary changes thanks :)
How can I make the above constraints follow my logic? I tried with AndBoolAnd() and things get worse with that. 

Or may be it is not possible to model what I expect. .